# Is it possible to ignore a variable when calling a function ? (ActionScript3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a function that is triggered when clicking on a button.

```
function button_clicked(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    mySharedObject.data.curr = event.currentTarget;
    mySharedObject.data.curr.background = true;
    mySharedObject.data.curr.backgroundColor = 0xFEDCA2;
    boxText.text = "this is some text";
}
```

Now I want to call this function in another way (when the user does something other than clicking on the button).

So I did :

```
button_clicked(null);
```

It's working, but the thing is, I don't need `mySharedObject.data.curr` when calling this way. (as it creates an error. `currentTarget` doesn't exist when using the other way and can't exist). I just need the boxText.text (and other things that I'll add)

Is there a way, when calling `button_clicked`, to ignore mySharedObject.data.curr in the function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doable, but you need to explicitly check for null in order to call it like that. In fact, the common `init()` function is called the "other way" and is declared as `function init(e:Event=null):void` but the parameter is plain ignored. You immediately request something off your passed event, thus you cannot call your function with null parameter. You can plain wrap your request to `mySharedObject` in this case with a simple if check.

```
function button_clicked(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if (event && event.currentTarget) {
        mySharedObject.data.curr = event.currentTarget;
        mySharedObject.data.curr.background = true; 
        mySharedObject.data.curr.backgroundColor = 0xFEDCA2;
    }
    boxText.text = "this is some text";
}
```

Asking for both object to not be null is required in case someone (you elsewhere) would desire to call `button_clicked(new Event("dummy"))` which might not have its `currentTarget` field populated.

Comment: It will fail if **event** is **null**.

Comment: @Organis then `if (event) if (event.currentTarget) {...}`, however I was under an impression that such a check does fail if `event` is null without generating an exception. Hmm.

Comment: We, humans, see the whole picture and can tell that if **event** is **null** then it is not necessary to check the rest of condition. Flash Player, however, is not that smart so it just calculates the whole expression, failing inevitably. On the other hand, a ternar expression inside the conditional, like **if (event? event.target: false)**, has chances to pass safely. Cannot check at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is certainly workable and what I used to do, but now I usually follow a pattern where I just separate it out in to another function and call which ever one as needed.

Something like this:

```
function button_clicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
    mySharedObject.data.curr = event.currentTarget;
    mySharedObject.data.curr.background = true; 
    mySharedObject.data.curr.backgroundColor = 0xFEDCA2;
    setBoxLabel("this is some text");
}

function setBoxLabel(inputText:String){
    boxText.text = inputText;
}

// can manually call as needed
setBoxLabel("this is some text");
```

Then I don't really need to wonder (upon revisiting it in the future) why that null check is there.